# JSON Schema if/then require nested object

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON:

```
{
    "i0": {
        "j0": {
            "a0": true
        }
    },
    "i1": {
        "j1": {
            "a1": "stuff"
        }
    }
}
```

I want a validation:
 If `a0` is true, `a1` should be required.

My schema is currently:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "id": "id",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "i0",
        "i1"
    ],
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "i0": {
                        "j0": {
                            "a0": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "i1": {
                        "j1": {
                            "required": [
                                "a1"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This conditional seems to not actually be run. Alternatively, I have have seen gotten a very similar conditional to work if I try to put the `required` on the same level as the value I am checking. As in:

```
"allOf": [
    {
        "if": {
            "a0": true
        },
        "then": {
            "required": [
                "a1"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

but this would require `a1` to be under `j0` along with `a1`.
How do I require an object under `j1` based on a value under `j0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "if":{
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
      "i0":{
        "type":"object",
        "properties":{
          "j0":{
            "type":"object",
            "required":["a0"]
          }
        },
        "required":["j0"]
      }
    },
    "required":["i0"]
  },
  "then":{
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
      "i1":{
        "type":"object",
        "properties":{
          "j1":{
            "type":"object",
            "required":["a1"]
          }
        },
        "required":["j1"]
      }
    },
    "required":["i1"]
  }
}
```

You have to use the overall structure within the `if`/`then` keywords, starting with whatever common root they have.  In this case, their paths begin to diverge at the `i0`/`i1` property, so you have to include the entire structure from that point.

The `type` keywords ensure that you have an object, otherwise the schema could pass validation when other types, like `string`s or `boolean`s, are used.

The `required` keywords ensure that the `if`/`then` subschemas only match on objects which actually contain the `i0.j0.a0`/`i1.j1.a1` property paths, respectively.

Additionally, the `required` keywords for the `a0`/`a1 properties only specify that they *exist*.  You can add more validation to that subschema if you need it.

Comment: Highlighting that you need to repeat the "properties" keyword at every level like you did - if not, like the OP did, "j1" and "a0" are treated as unknown/extension keywords that are simply not evaluated, instead of as property names. Because Json schema allows unknown keywords, the OP's schema is still grammatically valid unfortunately, making it hard to find the error.

Comment: The value of a key in the `properties` key word must be a JSON Schema. In furture, consider testing the value of each key from your `properties` key words. =]